# unexpected unqualified-id before 'double'

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a simple code that converts Litre to Gallon. It is a very simple code with only 3 functions in total and I run the program expecting things to go well. And for some reason I encountered the following errors, which have left me confused for hours.

> Error  C2062   type 'double' unexpected
>
> Error  C2065   'gallon': undeclared identifier
>
> Error  C2065   'gallon': undeclared identifier

And here's the code

---

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double litreUsed();
double litreToGallon();

int main()
{
    litreUsed();
    litreToGallon();

    return 0;
}

double litreUsed() {
    double litre;
    cout << "Enter the amount of gasoline used: \n";
    cin >> litre;
    return litre;
}

double litreToGallon() {
    double litre, double gallon;// Line 24
    gallon = litre * 0.264179;
    return gallon;
}
```

As you can see in my code, I have already declared the gallon in line 25 and it still says I didn't? I hope someone here wouldn't mind explaining the errors to me.

Comment: `double litre; double gallon;` or `double litre, gallon;`.

Comment: You just need `double litre, gallon`

Comment: Apparently everybody failed to explain in their answers that, because of the error in the line `double litre, double gallon;`, the `gallon` variable is not known to the complier and it generates the second and the third error messages (for the usage of the unknown variable `gallon` in lines #25 and #26.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably mean

```
double litre; double gallon;
```

or

```
double litre, gallon;
```

but in reality, `litre` should be a parameter of the function:

```
double litreToGallon(double litre) {
    double gallon = litre * 0.264179;
    return gallon;
}
```

or simply

```
double litreToGallon(double litre) {
    return litre * 0.264179;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double litre, double gallon;
```

is invalid C++. You probably meant

```
double litre, gallon;
```

or

```
double litre; double gallon;
```

Comment: You ought to explain that this change on its own will just lead to use of uninitialized variable.  And we can't be sure that OP has asked for a sensible set of warnings (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`).